# Square root of squares of two distances. (Triangle ineqality for such metric.)

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, metric-spaces

How to prove that such inequality holds for some metric space E?

I tried $\sqrt{a+b}\leq \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}$ and triangle rule, but I still cannot prove it.
Is it possible? I thinks that yes, because it's a part of exercise proving that $d(x,y)=\sqrt{d_E(x_1, y_1)^2 + d_E(x_2, y_2)^2}$ is metric.
(Here $d_E(x_1,y_1) = |x_1-y_1|$.)

\begin{align*}
    \sqrt{d_E(x_1, y_1)^2 + d_E(x_2, y_2)^2}
        &\leq \sqrt{d_E(x_1, z_1)^2 + d_E(x_2, z_2)^2}
            + \sqrt{d_E(z_1, y_1)^2 + d_E(z_2, y_2)^2}\\
\end{align*}

How to prove it?